# flink on kubernetes load external jars to cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am deploying a flink cluster on kubernetes (Session Cluster), and i wanted to know if there is any configuration (on flink-conf.yaml) that i will load external jars to the cluster.

As far i know flink will load all jars under lib/ folder, but lets say i want to upload jar for metrics, and i dont want put it manually in lib folder (becuase every deployment it will delete it), and i dont want make lib/ folder a mount.

The solution i want is to make a /mnt/external-jars library (that will be a mount), and flink will load to it`s classpath all the jars inside this directory.

Is it possible in some way?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the config option `pipeline.classpaths` which takes a semicolon separated list of classpaths. This config option is read when you run the Flink client. The classpaths will be added to the generated Flink `JobGraph` before it is submitted to the cluster. Note, that the classpaths must be accessible from the cluster nodes.

```
pipeline.classpaths: file:///mnt/external-jars/MyJar.jar;file:///foobar/other-jars/MyJar2.jar
```